# Paypal IPN with empty post data

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using the Paypal IPN system with a listener script using [ipnlistener.php](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/ipnlistener.php).  Since one day, Paypal hasn't sent any post data to my script. It can't be a problem with the code itself, because the $_POST variables are empty. So if there are no &_POST variables i cant handle anything. (tried it with sandbox and live)

The ipnlistener class throws the exception:

*exception 'Exception' with message 'No POST data found.'*

Is someone having the same trouble with it?

Thanks in advance..

**UPDATE 1**

I also scanned my log files and found a view logs which doesn't make any sense. Every once in a while this exception appears:

*exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid response status: 302'*

But there is no redirection...

Do i have to modify my curl options?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/api_cert_chain.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri); //$uri = https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data); // For paypal response encoded POST variables
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location); // false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout); // 30
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

It also doesn't matter if i use fsockopen instead of curl

**UPDATE 2**

So today i switched from the hosted webspace to a vm of my own. I copied everything from the webserver and tried it again. Oh look, it works. I don't exactly know why, but it has something to do with the apache2 configuration. I checked every log available on the hosted webspace, but i couldn't find anything related. I also don't know how the apache is compiled on the webspace. I think there is a version and/or module complication. The php versions are the same...

If anybody finds a solution/reason, let me know :)

So far.....thank you all....

Comment: Not exactly a programming question.

Comment: Yes and no, maybe my problem relies on the code in ipnlistener. Paypal turned off the support for http 1.0 header October 7th. Maybe the old ipnlistener class doesn't work anymore...the curl options are set to http 1.1 but who knows...

Comment: Check the IPN logs on Paypal, what are the responses?

Comment: @DavidNguyen 
They're listed as following: failed and http response code 503. It's weird becouse the $_POST variables are empty, so i can't build a valid response to post it to Paypal.

Comment: Means IPN is not even touching your server, check the notify url in the originating source (eg. cart/button) or check the notify url in paypal settings.

Comment: The IPN is reaching the script. I can see the bot's try in my logfiles.